# Is the bit width of built-in integral value types fixed?

Tags: c#, primitive-types

I'm looking for an unamiguous info whether the bit width of (raw) integral types (like `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc.) in `C#` (and thus the mapping to CLI fixed-width types like `Byte`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, ...) is fixed (forever) or it might change in the future (language revision) and we could face similar situations like in C/C++, where the builtin type is *at least N bits wide*.

The motivation is: could we safely use `C#.int` as the *integral type using 32 bits for its value*, or is it better to just use `CLI.Int32` for the cases we want exactly 32 bits?

Comment: int is the same as Int32, it's just an alias. `int n` is the same as `Int32 n = new Int32()`

Comment: Check the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 4.1.5. E.g. "The `int` type represents signed 32-bit integers with values between –2147483648 and 2147483647"

Comment: So supposedly in the case the CLI introduces Int128, C# introduces new alias instead of shifting the current aliases, right?

Comment: Are you asking us to predict the future? All we know for sure, at the moment, is how the language is currently specified and that changing the definitions of all of these types later would be a horrifically large breaking change to the language, such that we can be fairly certain such a proposal would never get beyond the `-100` starting score.

Comment: You seem to have a C background. C is about the only language where the size of primitive integer types is not fixed.

Comment: If you where wondering what @Damien_The_Unbeliever meant when he said "beyond the `-100` starting score" read the MSDN blog post "[Minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The motivation is: could we safely use C#.int as the integral type
>   using 32 bits for its value, or is it better to just use CLI.Int32 for
>   the cases we want exactly 32 bits?

Technically, they are the same.

`int` is equal to `Int32`

Why we can represent the same type with two different names ? The idea is that the primitive types are probably the most commonly used, and so the C# team created aliases for the types in order to write code faster.

Based on the above, the declaration `int n` is equivalent to `Int32 n = new Int32()`

Also note that the C# features are only subset of the features of CLI. Which means that in CLI there may be types, which are not implemented in C# and vise versa. For example, in CLI there is no UInt32 (unsigned integer), but in C# it does.

Based on the above, if new type is implemented in CLI or C#, this doesn't mean that it will be implemented in the opposite. Also, I don't believe that someone will change the implementation of the already existing types as this will break compatibility.